# Can we fill the data in the textboxes in a sorted manner as it is in the Database in c#

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am currently using this code to load fields into textboxes:

```
this.empTableAdapter.Fill(this.empDataSet.emp);
```

but the problem if we add a data record with a lesser value of key element than that's already present in database when i click on view all button which invokes this method the last added data is appearing at the the end but i would like to have it appear in a sorted manner.

i Have setup two navigation buttons to navigate to next and previous field.

The data is being sorted in my database but when i invoke  it by the

```
this.empTableAdapter.Fill(this.empDataSet.emp);
```

its not getting updated like that.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this problem would be not to bind directly to the empTableAdapter, but instead use an intermediary [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx).

The way this works is that you assign the TableAdapter as the source for the BindingSource, and then use the BindingSource when data binding to your UI components.

The BindingSource has options to ensure that your data remains filtered and sorted, and is further supported by nice UI controls for paging/navigation.

I haven't used DataSets for a long time now, but as I recall this call all be created and wired up using the component toolbox and windows forms designer.